# ColdFusion won't start after applying the 9.0.1 update How do I roll it back?

Tags: coldfusion

I installed the Coldfusion 9.0.1 update and now The application server won't start. I'm concerned that I may have installed the 64 bit update on a 32bit server but I am not sure how to check it without a running CF instance.

When trying to start the CF9 service I get the following error:

"Windows could not start the ColdFusion 9 Application Server on Local Computer. For more information, review the System Event Log. If this is a non-Microsoft service, contact the service vendor, and refer to service-specific error code 2."

The Event log entry states:

"The ColdFusion 9 Application Server service could not be started. Check the server "coldfusion" log files for more information."

The last server log entry is from when I stopped the service before installing the update:

"Information","Thread-1","03/12/13","17:04:09",,"ColdFusion stopped"

My coldfusion logs don't seem to list any errors. The installation log claims that it was successfully installed.

At any rate I'd like to simply roll back the update but I'm unsure how to do that. I have a "C:\ColdFusion9\updater_backup" folder do I just drag the contents of that folder into the root directory in order to restore the previous version?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at this config file:

```
C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\logs\coldfusion-out.log
```

I saw a bunch of lines which read

```
Error loading: C:/ColdFusion9/runtime/jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
Error loading: C:/ColdFusion9/runtime/jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
Error loading: C:/ColdFusion9/runtime/jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
```

old jvm.config file:

java.home=C:/ColdFusion9/runtime/jre

Changing it to:
java.home=C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre

Fixed the issue